# Reading data from BBC micro:bit from Raspberry Pi command line

Tags: accelerometer, communication, bbc-microbit

I'm trying to use a [BBC micro:bit](https://microbit.org/) instead of a [LIS3DH accelerometer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2809) to read accelerometer data on a Raspberry Pi.
The LIS3DH is used in this project: https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-matrix-cube-for-pi
I'm hoping to replace it with the BBC micro:bit instead.

I'm unsure how to go about getting the accelerometer data out of the micro:bit.
I assumed I could simple connect to it using USB and query the data with a command but I haven't found any info about that.
Do I need to get into the micro:bit and program it to return the data first and then set up some sort of communication with it?

It would be nice to be able to test the data retrieval from command line but maybe I also need to write a pything script to communicate with the micro:bit?

I'm unsure in what end to start doing this.

Comment: You will need to do a small amount of code to redirect the accelerometer data to the USB. There is example on the following page https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000022103-outputing-serial-data-from-the-micro-bit-to-a-computer